# Oracle table create error ORA-00904 invalid identifier

Tags: sql, oracle

It's very interesting I don't know why I'm getting ORA-00904 invalid identifier when I'm trying to create a table with oracle.

```
CREATE TABLE animals
(
   CONSTRAINT animal_id NUMBER(6) PRIMARY_KEY,
   name VARCHAR2(25),
   CONSTRAINT license_tag_number NUMBER(10) UNIQUE,
   admit_date DATE NOT NULL,
   adoption_id NUMBER(5),
   vaccination_date DATE NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: If you do not name your primary key, unique, foreign key, and check constraints explicitly then you may regret it later on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When creating tables with `CREATE TABLE` in Oracle, you have at least four ways to specify constraints.

**In-line specification**

```
CREATE TABLE animals
(
   animal_id NUMBER(6) PRIMARY KEY,
   name VARCHAR2(25),
   license_tag_number NUMBER(10) UNIQUE,
   admit_date DATE NOT NULL,
   adoption_id NUMBER(5),
   vaccination_date DATE NOT NULL
);
```

**In-line specification with explicit constraints' names**

```
CREATE TABLE animals
(
   animal_id NUMBER(6) CONSTRAINT animal_id_pk PRIMARY KEY,
   name VARCHAR2(25),
   license_tag_number NUMBER(10) CONSTRAINT animal_tag_no_uq UNIQUE,
   admit_date DATE NOT NULL,
   adoption_id NUMBER(5),
   vaccination_date DATE NOT NULL
);
```

**Out-line specification**

```
CREATE TABLE animals
(
   animal_id NUMBER(6) ,
   name VARCHAR2(25),
   license_tag_number NUMBER(10),
   admit_date DATE NOT NULL,
   adoption_id NUMBER(5),
   vaccination_date DATE NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (animal_id),
   UNIQUE (license_tag_number)
);
```

**Out-line specification with explicit constraints' names**

```
CREATE TABLE animals
(
   animal_id NUMBER(6) ,
   name VARCHAR2(25),
   license_tag_number NUMBER(10),
   admit_date DATE NOT NULL,
   adoption_id NUMBER(5),
   vaccination_date DATE NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT animal_id_pk PRIMARY KEY (animal_id),
   CONSTRAINT animal_tag_no_uq UNIQUE (license_tag_number)
);
```

If you don't explicitly specify constraints names, they are generated automatically by the system, and read something like `SYS_C0013321`. I find the last way the most readable, because you see which constraints are created, and can manage them using user-friendly names (e. g. using view `user_constraints`).

By the way, there's a typo in your code: you should use `PRIMARY KEY` instead of `PRIMARY_KEY`.

Answer (score 2):

This is correct code, you must remove `CONSTRAINT` word:

```
CREATE TABLE animals
(
   animal_id NUMBER(6) PRIMARY KEY,
   name VARCHAR2(25),
   license_tag_number NUMBER(10) UNIQUE,
   admit_date DATE NOT NULL,
   adoption_id NUMBER(5),
   vaccination_date DATE NOT NULL
);
```

but you can also use constraints for PK and UNIQUE as below:

```
CREATE TABLE animals
(
   animal_id NUMBER(6) not null,
   name VARCHAR2(25),
   license_tag_number NUMBER(10) UNIQUE,
   admit_date DATE NOT NULL,
   adoption_id NUMBER(5),
   vaccination_date DATE NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT animals_PK PRIMARY KEY (animal_id) ,
   CONSTRAINT l_tag_number_uq UNIQUE (license_tag_number) 
);
```

It is good practice to use constraints because they give you a friendly name/short description.

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/49f0f/1/0)

Comment: According to oracle docs, if I'm declaring something PRIMARY_KEY I don't need to set NOT NULL, because PRIMARY_KEY it's the combination of NOT NULL and UNIQUE constrains.

Comment: @ZbarceaChristian Yes, of course, but I think is good practice to declare it. It's more readable for me ;).

Comment: I just copy+pasted your code and I'm getting the following error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Comment: @ZbarceaChristian It's work for me, I added fiddle demo. I corrected first code too.

Answer (score 0):

I think there some mistake here :

Catch this example :

```
CREATE TABLE "name_of_table"

    ("column_1" "data_type",

    "column_2" "data_type",

    "column_3" "data_type",

    CONSTRAINT column_name PRIMARY KEY (column_1, column_2)

    ... );
```

Your code suppose :

CREATE TABLE animals(

```
CREATE TABLE animals
(
   animal_id NUMBER(6) PRIMARY_KEY,
   name VARCHAR2(25),
   license_tag_number NUMBER(10) UNIQUE,
   admit_date DATE NOT NULL,
   adoption_id NUMBER(5),
   vaccination_date DATE NOT NULL
);
```

You may check the example [here](http://psoug.org/reference/tables.html)

Comment: @ZbarceaChristian: This is because there's a typo in the code: you should use `PRIMARY KEY` instead of `PRIMARY_KEY`.

Answer (score 0):

I am creating a table of employee
Create table employee ( emp_id number(10), emp_name varchar(10), salary number(10));
I am getting an error of invalid identifier

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32670594)